# Install KVM on Ubuntu 13.10 server

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

How do I install/enable KVM on Ubuntu 13.10 server?

I executed the following steps

```
egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager
sudo adduser test1 libvirtd
```

Did not get any installation issue. But when I try to execute

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

I'm getting the following error

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor 
error: Cannot recv data: Connection reset by peer
```

I repeated the above installation process on different machine, which is also having Ubuntu 13.10 server. On this machine I'm getting the following error

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

Need help on these issues.

Comment: What is the output of `egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo` and `kvm-ok`?

Answer (score 1):

For `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock:No such file or directory` error:

check if root its in the default group (libvirtd), watch the logs (/var/log/messages),
check:

```
virsh 'net-list '
```

and see if its really exist a default option.
this problem can be also that libvirtd its not running, if its that so try:

```
service libvirtd restart
/etc/init.d/libvirt restart
```

or check if its in the rc.d files, start it up when the machine boots.http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/The_daemon_cannot_be_started

Comment: on my machine the daemon is not present ... I have installed the following package: `qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager`